# Google Maps API distance matrix over sea

Tags: google-maps

I am using the google maps api in a test version to calculate the travel distance between two or more adresses. Now, usually, this is not a problem at all, considering that the distance matrix does exactly that. But when I try to get the distance between two points, let's say Berlin and New York, seperated by sea, I run into problems, the API returns zero_results. I assume this is because the travel mode is "driving" as by default, yet I can not find a more fitting mode in the documentation. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro#travel_modes.

Am I using the wrong product? Is there a travel mode I missed? Hope somebody can help me with this, thanks.

The API call I use is 
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Berlin&destinations=New+York&key=MY_KEY

The response I get is

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "New York City, New York, USA" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "Berlin, Deutschland" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Comment: Your only option at the present is to compute the straight line distance between the two cities.

Answer (score 2):

The currently supported [Travel modes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro#travel_modes) are driving, walking, bicycling and transit. So you would probably choose the `transit` mode as you obviously can't drive, walk or bicycle from Berlin to NY.

For the `transit` mode, the supported `transit_mode` values are bus, subway, train, tram and rail. So again, nothing here that allows for crossing the ocean...

I would assume that these are the only possible travel modes you can get today via the API.

Comment: Okay, for clarification, it is currently not possible to use the google maps API for finding the travelling distance between two points if the ocean is involved?

Comment: You can find the straight line (as the crow flies) distance.

Comment: @geocodezip Could you give me an API-example for this? Because I am not able to find that.

Comment: Geometry library has it all.